"Dataset specified in the query ('') is not consistent with Destination dataset " error in Bigquery
I tried creating a scheduled query with  EXPORT DATA statement in bigquery using python but, I get an error "Dataset specified in the query ('') is not consistent with Destination dataset 'ORDERS'."
This is the query which I had used within my scheduled query,
> EXPORT DATA OPTIONS ( uri = 'gs://-'||'{}'||'-*.parquet', format =
> 'PARQUET', overwrite = true) AS ( SELECT * FROM ``.{}.{} WHERE {} >
> '{}');

// The select statement in the Export data selects from the ORDERS dataset.

I'd suggest more details is desirable.  I'm not following the artifact posted above.  Can you expand it with more context?
